# Xcode stopped reading from a text file when file was changed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple text file with strings of text separated by line breaks. I used this code to read from the file:

```
 if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "txt") {
        do {
            let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
            let allQuestions = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
```

This is not all of it, but the code isn't the problem. Everything was working fine, but I needed to change the data in the text file. I created a new file, deleted the old one, and imported a new one to Xcode. Now my app crashes every time because it's not reading any data from the file. I thought maybe it was because my new file was in Chinese rather than English, but when I replaced the old file I'm getting the same problem. No code was changed. I tried restarting Xcode, cleaning the project, etc. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I had to manually add the file to "Copy Bundle Resources" under Build Phases. Not sure why Xcode does it automatically once, but not this time....